# Redirecting aws cli v2 to file adds extra control characters

Tags: bash, docker, aws-cli

If I run the following command:

```
docker run -v "$PWD/aws":/root/.aws --rm -it amazon/aws-cli wafv2 list-ip-sets --profile dev --scope=CLOUDFRONT --region=us-east-1 --color off
```

I get the following output:

```
{
    "IPSets": []
}
```

If I run the following command:

```
docker run -v "$PWD/aws":/root/.aws --rm -it amazon/aws-cli wafv2 list-ip-sets --profile dev --scope=CLOUDFRONT --region=us-east-1 --color off > test.txt
```

I get the following in test.txt:

```
[?1h=
{[m
    "IPSets": [][m
}[m

[K[?1l>
```

I think these are xterm control codes or something - in any case, how do I get the contents of test.txt to match what is output to the terminal? I am on a Mac but my solution needs to work on Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently that -it parameter being passed to Docker was the problem. Passing just just -i made it work.